# Java Spring XML LocalDate deserialization produces null values

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson, deserialization

I am working on a proof of concept, where a microservice is receiving xml requests which are generated from wsdl files. The goal is to translate them into json format and forward them. I am trying to test them with unit tests. As it turned out the dates cannot be deserialized from the xml file.
The DateWrapper object in the controller has nulls as values so it dies right at the beginning:

`DateWrapper(dateTime=null, date=null)`

What am I missing?

**in the pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/test/wsdl/dateTest.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <bindingFiles>
                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                            </bindingFiles>
                            <packagenames>
                                <packagename>foo.bar.converter.wsdl</packagename>
                            </packagenames>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**the wsdl used for java class generation:**

```
<definitions
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="">
    <types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="dateWrapper">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                        <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

**the generated java class**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "dateTime",
    "date"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "dateWrapper")
public class DateWrapper
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 7702L;
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OffsetDateTimeAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected OffsetDateTime dateTime;
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    protected LocalDate date;
```

**the service methods to convert **

```
    public String convertDateToJson(DateWrapper dateWrapper) {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();
        gsonBuilder.disableHtmlEscaping();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        String result = gson.toJson(dateWrapper, DateWrapper.class);
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public String fileToJsonString(String path) {
        try(InputStream in=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)){
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(in,
                    JsonNode.class);
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
            return jsonString;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**the date adapter (the other one is looks like this one but it converts to OffsetDateTime)**

```
public class OffsetDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, OffsetDateTime> {

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime unmarshal(String inputDate) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(OffsetDateTime inputDate) throws Exception {
        return inputDate.toString();
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
@RestController
public class ConverterController {

    @Autowired
    ConverterService converterService;
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/convert-date", consumes = "application/xml")
    public String convertDateToJson(@RequestBody DateWrapper dateWrapper, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        String result = this.converterService.convertDateToJson(dateWrapper);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ConverterControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldConvertDates() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/convert-date")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .content(this.getResourceAsString("classpath:test/request/dateTest.xml"));
        String json = converterService.fileToJsonString("test/expected/date.json");
        mvc.perform(request).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().json(json));
    }

}
```

**the xml used for the request**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dateWrapper>
    <dateTime>2002-09-24-06:00</dateTime>
    <date>2002-09-24</date>
</dateWrapper>
```

**the json used for the test**

```
{"dateTime": "2002-09-24-06:00","date": "2002-09-24"}
```

Comment: `2002-09-24-06:00` is not a date and time. It’s a date with a UTC offset.

Comment: Nice catch, you are right! Fixed it, still not working